# How can I loop thru JSON to find and compare value?

Tags: javascript, json

#### variables:

##### user.uid = 11111111

#### Question:

How can I loop thru this and check if `user.uid` is assigned to staff or member?:

```
{
  "11111111" : "staff",
  "22222222" : "user"
}
```

My code:

```
  fetch('link')
  .then(response =>
    response.json()
  )
  .then(data => {
    const prmUid = user.uid;
    if (data.prmUid == "staff") {
      console.log("user is a staff");
    };
  });
```

This chunk of code doesn't work: `if (data.prmUid == "staff") {`, because it's requesting `data.user.uid`, how do I loop thru that using `if ()`?

Comment: you should check data[prmUid] which is different than data.prmUid

Comment: Please take the [tour]. We don't mark questions SOLVED, and we don't accept answers in comments. @ITgoldman, please don't put answers in comments. You short-circuit the process, as we've seen here.

Answer (score 0):

`data.prmUid` lets you access the prmUid property of the data object. `data[prmUid]` lets you access the attribute of the data object, where the name equals the value of the prmUid variable. Example: if `prmUid === "foo"`, then `data[prmUid]` would be equivalent to `data["foo"]` or `data.foo`.

```js
const responseData = {
  "11111111" : "staff",
  "22222222" : "user"
};

const processResponse = (data, user) => {
    const prmUid = user.uid;
    if (data[prmUid] === "staff") {
      console.log("user is a staff");
    };
};

processResponse(responseData, { "uid": "11111111" });
```